# Group's equality

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $H, K, N$ be subgroups of G such that $H  \leqslant N$. Prove that $HK\cap N = H(K\cap N)$.

I have shown that $H(K\cap N) \leqslant  HK\cap N$.
Can someone help me for the opposite?

Comment: sorry for my mistake, i meant H(K$\cap$N) is subset of HK$\cap$N

Answer (score 0):

To prove that $ HK \cap N \subseteq H(K\cap N)$ (with $H \subseteq N$) we must show that given 
$$
x \in G: x= h_x k_x = n_x \\
h_x \in h, k_x \in K, n_x \in N$$
there is some pair $(h' \in H,y \in G)$ such that
$$
x = h'y \\ (y \in K) \wedge (y \in N)
$$
(this is just the definition of $H(K\cap N)$).

Choose 
$$
h' = h_x \\y = h_x^{-1}n_x$$

Then since 
$ n_x = x = h_xk_x $,
$$
y = h_x^{-1}n_x = h_x^{-1}h_x k_x =k_x \in K$$

And since $ H \subseteq N $, and $h_x^{-1} \in H$, $h_x^{-1} \in N$, and since $N$ is a group,
$$ y = h_x^{-1}n_x \in N$$
Having shown $ (y \in K) $ and $(y \in N)$ we have proven the statement.